# Update App for older SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

We have developed an application before iOS 8.0  release and with Base SDK 7.1.

Now our customer asked us for a change of the menu of the application but not to be combatible with iOS 8.1.

So we want to upload an update for iOS 7.1 Base SDK only and not for the latest Base SDK(iOS 8.1).

Is there any way?

iOS 7.1 does not appear as a selection to Base SDK drop down menu.

Comment: You can use the iOS 8 SDK and set the deployment target to iOS 7. This means the app will be build with the new iOS SDK but will be able to run on device running iOS 7. Just make sure you are nog using any new API, of check if the new API is available before calling it.

Comment: Deployment target has been set to 6.1. If i set iOS 8 SDK , have i to customise the app for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus too?If i have to do  this,we want to avoid all of this.

Comment: proceed with xcode5 bro

Comment: No aslong as you do not have any iPhone 6 or 6+ launch screens the app will not be compatible with the iPhone 6/6+. But be aware that Apple will require iPhone 6/6+ support in Februari. Also if you have setup you app using correct Autolayout to Resizing mask you will do just fine on the bigger devices. If you have a specific design for 3.5" and 4" device you are in a big bag of hurt. I suggest you make you Apps design scalable.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for your answer.To conclude, if i understood right i will submit my app with Base SDK Latest iOS 8.1 without any customisation for "big" iPhones and without Launch Screens for them and will be fine for approval.Right? Also,i handle each size of screen separately until now,and it will be painful to customise it at that moment for the bigger screens.Also there is not so much time to do this.

Comment: Yes that is correct, But for next time, never ever use specific designs per screen size. You of course use some customization per screen size. Because if you need to update the after January next year you **will need support the iPhone 6 & 6+**

Comment: Yes i will keep it in mind for the next time.Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8 brings other changes, apart from those that you've outlined in the comments.

For example you'll have to add support for the way iOS 8 handles push notifications, location services and probably other things, depending on what your app does.

So the best thing to do is to compile with the iOS7 SDK that you've developed against and release that version to the store.

You can get the iOS7 SDK by following [this tutorial](https://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/how-to-get-back-the-ios-7-sdk-after-upgrading-to-xcode-6/).

Or just download [Xcode 5.1.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1/xcode_5.1.1.dmg) and use that to submit your app.

Starting at the 1st of February, though, you'll need to have support for iOS 8 in your app.

Comment: Andrew i have not any compilation issues for iOS 8.1. All work properly on iOS 8.1 but we cannot support "big" iPhones at this time,because graphics content is needed to be redesigned and some screen elements will have to be repositioned and this will be time-consuming.So,will be a problem if i upload the application with the latest SDK but without providing launch screens for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: No, that's totally fine. As long as it works properly on iOS8, it's all good.